# Python getting how many numbers from user and generating that many random numbers

Tags: python

I wanna generate list of random numbers, and I want to get the length of that list from the user. So I write the code like below:

```
randNum = input()
randList = random.sample(range(0,10000), randNum)
```

I know this is wrong, but this is what I want to build.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: "I know this is wrong..." Why is it wrong? What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead? You should `print(randList)` to see if it has numbers like you want.

Comment: Take a look at [Generating random number list in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-random-number-list-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

input() method returns a string.
So randNum variable is a string, convert it into integer using int()

Try this

```
randNum = int(input())
randList = random.sample(range(0,10000), randNum)
```

Or this

```
randNum = input()
randList = random.sample(range(0,10000), int(randNum))
```

Both works.

Another error you might encounter is when input value is greater or equal to 10000, there you can use if-else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the randNum to in integer.
I think this is what you want:

```
randNum = int(input())
randList = np.random.sample(randNum)*10000
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can go wrong is if the user doesn't provide a valid input that can be converted to integer.

So the only care you should take is handle that:

```py
import random
randNum: str = input()
randList: list = []
try:
    randNum: int = int(randNum) # converting str() to int()
except ValueError:
    print("Please provide a valid natural number!")
else:
    randList: list[int] = random.sample(range(0,10000), randNum)
print(randList)
```